# Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are finite sets such that $A \subseteq B$ and $|A| = |B|$, then $A = B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are finite sets such that $A \subseteq B$ and $|A| = |B|$, then $A = B$. Does the same result hold if $A$ and $B$ are not finite?

Solution:

To show $A=B$ it remains to show that $B\subseteq A$. Consider the set $B\setminus A$. Since $|A|=|B|$ and $A\subseteq B$, it follows that $B\setminus A$ is empty because $B = A \cup (B \setminus A)$ is a disjoint union. Then $|B| = |A| + |B \setminus A|$, thus $|B \setminus A|= 0$ as all cardinalities in questions are finite. Hence, $B\subseteq A$. Finally, $A=B$.

Would the proof above be correct, and "Does the same result hold if $A$ and $B$ are not finite?"

Not sure

Comment: If A is a set of even numbers, B is set of all natural numbers, then clearly |A|=|B| and $A \subseteq B $ but A =/= B

Comment: The jump is where you say it follows.

Answer (score 2):

For the finite case let |A|=n then we can list elements of A as $$a_1,a_2,...,a_n$$

Since |B|=|A|=n, we can list  elements of B as $$b_1,b_2,...,b_n$$

Since $A\subseteq B$ every element $a_i$ appears as an element  $b_j$, since the number of elements  are equal, there would not be any element of $B$ which is not in $A$

Thus $A=B$
For the infinite case consider $N$ and $Q$ where they the same cardinality and  $N\subseteq Q$ but they are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is immediate. For the second, the  result is not true in general, you can try with $A=2\mathbb{N}$ and $B=\mathbb{N}$.